# MainMenu: How display all MenuItems in sequence independent of size of Form or resizing?

Tags: delphi, menuitem, delphi-10.3-rio

I have a `MainMenu` that have 14 `MenuItems` and want know how all these items can be displayed in sequence independent of size of Form or resizing?

Here is how the items is being displayed:

[image]

Expected (but independent of size of Form/resizing):

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for the [`MinWidth`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Forms_TForm_Constraints.html) property?

Comment: @Sami, not exists this property here.

Comment: @BrowJr as shown when you click the link the FORM has this property. Setting the forms min width wider than the menu with all the items would keep the form from being shrunk to the point the menu gets put on multiple lines. In the property list for a form it is a sub item of Constraints.

Comment: @Brian, worked. Thank you very much!